# Какую информацию безопасно хранить в sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, php

Нужно чтобы информация после отключения и включения компьютера сохранялось вот для этого использую sessionStorage, и храню в нем информацию о цене продуктов, и общую цену выбранных продуктов.

Безопасно ли использовать sessionStorage  в этом случае и как лучше сделать ?

На сервере использую валидацию для проверки цены.

Comment: Всё, что хранится у клиента, клиент может подредактировать или удалить. Или не храните у клиента, или каким-то образом защищайте (подпись, шифрование или просто проверки на сервере)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Нужно чтобы информация после отключения и включения компьютера сохранялось вот для этого использую sessionStorage*

Информация из `sessionStorage` удаляется после закрытия вкладки/браузера, поэтому врядли Вы можете использовать его в случаях включения/выключения ПК. Вместо этого используйте `localStorage`.

Насчет безопасности: Согласно GDPR Вы не имеется права хранить любую информацию с помощью которой можно идентифицировать пользователя, поэтому оцените данные и решайте.

Comment: localStorage НЕБЕЗОПАСЕН!  https://habr.com/post/349164/ тогда с таким же успехом храните все в COOKIES)

Comment: И в чем собственно проблема? Чем он небезопасен? Тем что в нём нельзя хранить данные пользователя? Ну как бы да, я написал, смотрите выше. Насчет статьи... Прочтите еще раз её, и скажите что кроме "хранения личных данных" запрещено?

Comment: признаю) тут безвыходная ситуация) только localStorage

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим localStorage, sessionStorage cookies

localStorage, sessionStorage и файлы cookie - это все клиентские решения для хранения. Данные сеанса хранятся на сервере, где он остается под вашим прямым контролем.

**LocalStorage**

> **Плюсы:**
>
> 1. Веб-хранилище можно рассматривать упрощенно как усовершенствование
>      файлов cookie, обеспечивая гораздо большую емкость. Если вы посмотрите
>      на исходный код Mozilla, мы увидим, что 5120 КБ (5 МБ, равный 2,5
>      миллионам символов в Chrome) является размером хранилища по умолчанию
>      для всего домена. Это дает вам значительно больше возможностей для
>      работы, чем обычный cookie 4 Кбайт.
> 2. Данные не отправляются обратно на
>      сервер для каждого HTTP-запроса (HTML, изображения, JavaScript, CSS и
>      т.д.) - уменьшение количества трафика между клиентом и сервером.
> 3. Данные, хранящиеся в localStorage, сохраняются до явного удаления.
>      Сделанные изменения сохраняются и доступны для всех текущих и будущих
>      посещений сайта.
>
> **Минусы:**
>
> 1. Он работает по политике одного и того же происхождения. Таким образом,
>      сохраненные данные будут доступны только по одному и тому же
>      происхождению.

**SessionStorage**

> **Плюсы:**
>
> 1. Он похож на localStorage.
> 2. Данные не являются постоянными, т.е. Данные доступны только для
>      каждого окна браузера.
>      Данные доступны только во время сеанса страницы. Сделанные изменения
>      сохраняются и доступны для текущей страницы, а также для будущих
>      посещений сайта в том же окне. После закрытия окна хранилище
>      удаляется.
>
> **Минусы:**
>
> 1. Данные доступны только внутри окна/вкладки, в котором она была
>      установлена.
> 2. Подобно localStorage, работает с политикой того же происхождения.
>      Таким образом, сохраненные данные будут доступны только по одному и
>      тому же происхождению.

**Cookies**

> **Плюсы:**
>
> По сравнению с другими, никаких.
>
> **Минусы:**
>
> 1. Предел 4K предназначен для всего файла cookie, включая имя,
>      значение, дату истечения срока годности и т.д. Чтобы поддерживать
>      большинство браузеров, сохраните имя до 4000 байт и общий размер
>      файла cookie под 4093 байтами.
> 2. Данные отправляются обратно на сервер для каждого HTTP-запроса
>      (HTML, изображения, JavaScript, CSS и т.д.) - увеличение количества
>      трафика между клиентом и сервером.
>
>    Как правило, допускается следующее:
>
>    - Всего 300 куки
>    - 4096 байт за куки файл
>    - 20 файлов cookie для домена
>    - 81920 байт на домен (задано 20 файлов cookie максимального размера    4096 = 81920 байт).

Делаем выводы что для вашего магазина лучше всего хранить в LocalStorage, как сказал Alexandr Tovmach, но вы же храните только не важные данные о цене и о выбранных продуктов, так что тут не нужно напрягаться в плане безопасности. Все эти api выдают пользователю информацию через браузер! Если конечно вы их не закодируете)

Answer (score 1):

Всё, что вы оставляете на клиентской стороне по определнию не безопасно. Все данные, необходимо валидировать на стороне сервера.

Но если вы используете её для информации о корзине товаров, то вполне ок. Главное при оформлении заказа валидируйте наличие товара и цену с сервера.